# Log ip addresses used for requests

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using Proxy with Puppeteer. So for example I am going to webpage.com and it loads different resources in the background like css, js files, does ajax requests etc. I would like to log what IP address was used for every of those requests. I wonder if there is a good way to do that? I have tried to use page.on('request') listener and do the calls to a 3rd party IP service there, but I have noticed that sometimes proxy changes the IP even after that, so my logging was not 100% accurate.

Comment: Please share your attempt as a [mcve] so your context is apparent and we have something to work with. Thanks.